# issue with adding an empty row in a databound combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I want to add an empty row in my combobox with no value. This is in case a user selects something from the combobox and then want to deselect it. Without an empty row this is required as I have already pointed out that I can do DELETE click and set the selected index to -1. User wants an empty row right at the top of the combobox. I'm loading my combobox like this....

```
sql="Select ID, Name from TblReference"

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet

da.Fill(ds, "Dk")
```

'here I'm trying to add the extra row! This was previously supplied to me by @Plutonix. I am not able to get this to work.

```
Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables("Dk").NewRow
ds.Tables("Dk").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)

If ds.Tables("Dk").Rows.Count > 0 Then
    With c
      .DataSource = ds.Tables("Dk")
      .ValueMember = "ID"
      .DisplayMember = "Name"
      .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
 End If
```

In this case C - is a combobox name that I pass to this function. I'm using the same function for multiple comboboxes which is why I need it.

ERROR says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type
>   'SystemIconvertible'. Couldn't store system.data.datarow in ID column
>   expected type is int32

Comment: Your new row has no data in it like a "(Pick One)", "(None)" for the user, but otherwise how does it not work?  re: edit add some fake data - 0 for the Id should work - datatables are smart and can know whats allowed for each column

Comment: @plutonix - i get the error above. No, basically it's a drop down with a bunch of items, and I want an empty row. That's what's been asked of me.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing `ds.Tables("Dk").Rows.Add(dr, 0)` instead of `ds.Tables("Dk").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)`?

Comment: Refresh to see an edit  You should add an empty string and some number to fit the schema

Comment: @plutonix - yeah I'm doing the latter (insertAt)

Comment: And unless you want that empty row to show in all the cbo's which use that datasource, you should probably create a List from it

Comment: @plutonix - i do want to show in ALL.

Comment: That was Mark - **my** remedy was to add some data to your new row which will satisfy the schema ("", -1)

Comment: Can you not just add a union to your `SELECT` SQL statement? Place `ID=0,Name='' UNION` just after `Select`.

Comment: @plutonix - sorry for this. wrong synthax - i copied this for a different combobox and did ADD instead of InsertAt

Comment: @plutonix nice hat btw!

Comment: @Jinx88909 comment is another good way - let SQL do the work

Comment: @Jinx88909 -thanks for idea but it's already working with InsertAt - so I will leave it at that. Will def keep in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new row added to a `DataTable` has to conform to the data rules it read from the DB.  In your case, it knows that Id has to be a valid `Int32` but you did not supply any data for your row:

```
Dim dr = dtSample.NewRow
dr("Id") = -1
dr("Descr") = "(Blank)"
dtSample.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)

cboE.DataSource = dtSample
cboE.DisplayMember = "Descr"
cboE.ValueMember = "Id"
```

[image]

---

Another, perhaps better, way is the let SQL add the fake row.  In MySQL, it would be:

```
SELECT  -1 As Id, '(Pick One)' As Descr UNION ALL SELECT Id, Descr FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Since `Name` is often a reserved word, `Descr` is used for illustration purposes.

Comment: I don't think not setting the data would result in an "Unable to cast object of type..." message - probably something like a `NoNullAllowedException` if `AllowDBNull` was false (although I've not been able to get the columns to come out like that from a data adapter, even if the columns aren't nullable in the database, so using the default nulls for all columns works for me).

Comment: @MarkTo tell the truth, I didnt even notice the DataAdapter just the `Int32 and Id` part.   If the datatable at least picked up that it was a PK, a non null value makes sense.